# gulp watch not update while create new file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am working with gulp pug, and I make a watch task for gulp, It work fine when I edit/update the file but it does not work when I create a new file. what is the problem here? and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The src can not be an absolute path if you want Gulp watch to detect changes. You can make it work by defining a "Current Working Directory" (cwd)

Change:

```
gulp.watch('./src/**/*', ['pug']);
```

to:

```
gulp.watch('**/*', {cwd: ./src/}, ['pug']);
```

and it should work

Comment: "The src can not be an absolute path if you want Gulp watch to detect changes" can you point me to some relevant proof or reason of this?